# MySQL Workbench on Mac - Operation Failed for Server Adminstration

Tags: mysql, mamp, mysql-workbench

I am using "Configure Local Management" in MySQL Workbench for Mac for a MAMP server, and while my connection works, for some reason, I am getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCgI8.png)

It says `Operation failed: /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start is invalid`

While the `mysql` there does not exist, however, when I type in `mysql --version` in Terminal, it says I have 5.6.13 installed.

What could possible be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the MAMP installation doesn't use the standard way of installing a MySQL server. Better use the package from the MySQL homepage instead. It will also install the standard scripts for controlling the server. In your case find out where the MAMP installer writes the mysql.server script and use this path instead in the setup of your connection.

Btw: you can ignore this error if you never want to start/stop your server from within MySQL Workbench. The command is not mandatory.